# How to install a Local Git Repository Viewer Using GitList and Wamp?

Tags: php, git, wamp

I'm trying to install a local git repository viewer using gitlist and wamp. I'm very new in those technologies and any help would be very useful! I followed the following tutorial

https://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2012/09/03/how-to-install-a-local-git-repository-viewer-using-gitlist-and-wamp/
but it returns me an error!

```
USER@DESKTOP-C2RTCQF MINGW64 /c/wamp64/www/test(master)
$ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
bash: php: command not found
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: install php `sudo apt-get install php7.3`

Comment: Hey thank you! It also returns me this error!

User@DESKTOP-C2RTCQF MINGW64 /c/wamp64/www/test(master)
$ sudo apt-get install php7.3
bash: sudo: command not found

Comment: oh, I'm using windows 10.

Comment: run it without the sudo. sudo is for getting root access

Comment: Are you running Bash from within Windows? `apt-get` is a Linux based installer...

Comment: @CodeWizard User@DESKTOP-C2RTCQF MINGW64 /c/wamp64/www/test(master)
$ apt-get install php7.3
bash: apt-get: command not found


It also returns me an error!I'm getting mad :P :P

Comment: yeah, I'm a windows 10 user!

Comment: So its a different OS which does not have apt-get. apt-get is for Ubuntu and some other OS. What is the output of your `uname -a`

Comment: feeling completely dumb! Thank you :) @CodeWizard

Comment: Ok, windows not unix.!!!!! so install php on your windows

Comment: http://kizu514.com/blog/install-php7-and-composer-on-windows-10/

Comment: https://windows.php.net/download/ install from here

Comment: It didn't seem to be SO difficult...I tried the link that @НиколайЛубышев but when I test the connection, it also returns me an error...

C:\Users\USER>php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: ext\oci8_12c (─ίΊ ▐ΪάΊ ϊΫΊάΪⁿ Ίά ίΊΪΎΏώ≤Ϊί▀ ύ ΆάϋΎ±ώ≤Ή▌Ίύ ΈίώΪ. ΉΎΊ▄ϊά.), 

Looks that I have to be patient! :)

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=Unable+to+load+dynamic+library+%27oci8_12c%27&oq=Unable+to+load+dynamic+library+%27oci8_12c%27&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @НиколайЛубышев worked! Thank you!

Comment: Migrate to Linux!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `php` in your path.

The article mentioned this:

> Prerequisites: As aforementioned, Apache — PHP5.3

Follow those instructions on how to install it for your system:

http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

#### Verify that you have php in your path

```
# simply type php and see if there is an input
php

# check which php is your OS is using
# Where does the php execution located
which php
```